# Invalid reduction dimension 1 for input with 1 dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am developing a VAE using this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud). I have used keras tutorial code and developed my own VAE. However, when I run fit() function I get: `Invalid reduction dimension 1 for input with 1 dimensions. for '{{node Sum}} = Sum[T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, keep_dims=false](Mean, Sum/reduction_indices)' with input shapes: [?], [2] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <1 2>. What do I have to change?`

The code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('local path')
data, test_data = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2)
data.shape #(227845, 31)

class Sampling(layers.Layer):
"""Uses (z_mean, z_log_var) to sample z, the vector encoding a digit."""

def call(self, inputs):
    z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
    batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
    epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
    return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon
```

encoder:

```
latent_dim = 31

encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(31))
x = layers.Dense(100, activation="relu") (encoder_inputs)
x = layers.Dense(100, activation="relu")(x)
z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean")(x)
z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var")(x)
z = Sampling()([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, 
z_log_var, z], name="encoder")
encoder.summary()
```

decoder:

```
latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
x = layers.Dense(100, activation="relu")(latent_inputs)
x = layers.Dense(100, activation="relu")(x)
decoder_outputs = layers.Dense(31, activation="sigmoid")(x)
decoder = keras.Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name="decoder")
decoder.summary()
```

This is where I get the error:

```
vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
vae.fit(data, epochs=30, batch_size=128)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from `tf.reduce_mean` and `tf.reduce_sum`. In the `train_step` method of the `VAE` model, change this line:

```
reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.reduce_sum(
                    keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2)
                )
            )
```

To this:

```
reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(
                    keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=-1),keepdims=True)
```

Or:

```
reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(
                    keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=-1, keepdims=True))
```

And it should work.

Comment: It works now, however, I get NaN in reconstruction_loss and kl_loss all the time, does it have to do with the encoder and decoder layers? what should I do?

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634488/keras-variational-autoencoder-nan-loss and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962226/common-causes-of-nans-during-training

Comment: I tried changing the learning_rate and the dense layers but nothing, could you help me please?

Comment: It's really hard to debug something like that with a minimal amount of information.